# Private Data-explorer for a private Stack Overflow instance

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am using a "Stack Overflow for Teams", but my team needs backups and a good data explorer for it ... Is it possible to download a backup of my questions? Is it possible to explore all the details and statistics of my questions?

In other words, **is there a private version of `https://data.stackexchange.com/`,  to explore my private `https://stackoverflow.com/c/MyTeam`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [download a zip file](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387787-download-your-data) with all the data.

[image: Admin settings > Account information > (at the bottom) Download data]

The zip file contains the following files:

- accounts.json
- badges.json
- comments.json
- images.json
- posts.json
- posts2votes.json
- tags.json
- users.json
- users2badges.json

and a folder named `images` containing the images you uploaded.

The image filename is an uuid (without any - for example: `1e3c170751be483db646fadea963615f`) where as the `imageGuid` in the images.json does have a -, (for example: `1e3c1707-51be-483d-b646-fadea963615f`). In the posts.json you'll find that the `body` and `bodyMarkdown` have a full URL to your image, including your teamname: `https://stackoverflow.com/c/[teamname]/images/s/1e3c1707-51be-483d-b646-fadea963615f.png`. Some URL rewriting is required there.

Here is the schema for each file:

#### accounts.json

Accounts from users in your team

- `accountId` (number) *the accountid for the Stack Exchange network profile*
- `verifiedEmail` (string)

#### badges.json

Available badges

- `isCode`
- `tagBased`
- `single`
- `awardedCount`
- `id`
- `class`
- `badgeReasonTypeId`
- `awardFrequency`
- `description`
- `name`

#### comments.json

- `creationDate`
- `editCount`
- `postId`
- `id`
- `postCommentTypeId`
- `userId`
- `text`

#### images.json

- `creationDate`
- `imageGuid`
- `id`

#### posts.json

- `creationDate` (string)
- `favoriteCount` (number)
- `commentCount` (number)
- `answerCount` (number)
- `answerScore` (number)
- `score` (number)
- `id` (number)
- `postType` (string)
- `viewCount` (number)    *only for questions*
- `parentId` (number)     *only for answers*
- `ownerUserId` (number)
- `tags` (string)         *only for questions*
- `title` (string)        *only for questions*
- `bodyMarkdown` (string)
- `body` (string)

#### post2votes.json

- `creationDate`
- `voteTypeId`

  <sub>2. Upvote

  3. Downvote

  26. Fire feedback</sub>
- `userId`
- `postId`
- `id`
- `voterRepChange`
- `targetRepChange`
- `targetUserId`

#### tags.json

- `isSpecialTag`
- `count`
- `id`
- `creationDate`
- `name`

#### users.json

- `lastAccessDate` (string)
- `creationDate` (string)
- `answerCount` (number)
- `questionCount` (number)
- `goldBadges` (number)
- `silverBadges` (number)
- `bronzeBadges` (number)
- `views` (number)
- `reputation` (number)
- `id` (number)
- `userTypeId` (string)     *Admin;*
- `accountId` (number)
- `lastModifiedDate` (string)
- `lastLoginDate` (string)
- `location` (string)
- `title` (string)
- `profileImageUrl` (string)
- `realName` (string)
- `displayName` (string)

#### users2badges.json

- `date`
- `badgeId`
- `userId`
- `id`

Do note that the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer) is open source and can be hosted on premises.

Here is the example of the data you'll find:

#### Accounts

```json
[{
 "accountId": 1,
 "verifiedEmail": "your.name@example.com"
}]
```

#### Badges

```json
[{
 "isCode": false,
 "tagBased": false,
 "single": true,
 "awardedCount": 0,
 "id": 1,
 "class": "Bronze",
 "badgeReasonTypeId": "Post",
 "awardFrequency": 1,
 "description": "Answered first question with at least one up vote",
 "name": "Teacher"
}, {
 "isCode": false,
 "tagBased": false,
 "single": true,
 "awardedCount": 0,
 "id": 2,
 "class": "Bronze",
 "badgeReasonTypeId": "Post",
 "awardFrequency": 1,
 "description": "Asked first question with at least one up vote",
 "name": "Student"
}, {
 "isCode": false,
 "tagBased": false,
 "single": true,
 "awardedCount": 0,
 "id": 6,
 "class": "Bronze",
 "badgeReasonTypeId": "Other",
 "awardFrequency": 1,
 "description": "First up vote",
 "name": "Supporter"
}]
```

#### Comments

```json
[{
 "creationDate": "2021-04-27T06:36:06.877Z",
 "editCount": 0,
 "postId": 11,
 "id": 1,
 "postCommentTypeId": "Unknown",
 "userId": 1,
 "text": "It is cumbersome"
}]
```

#### Images

```json
[{
 "creationDate": "2021-04-04T12:25:46.493Z",
 "imageGuid": "23916c86-7f24-413a-bd5b-a6a58eb0a54c",
 "id": 1
}, {
 "creationDate": "2021-04-27T06:39:16.160Z",
 "imageGuid": "1e3c1707-51be-483d-b646-fadea963615f",
 "id": 2
}]
```

#### Posts

```json
[{
 "creationDate": "2021-04-04T11:47:48.813Z",
 "favoriteCount": 0,
 "commentCount": 0,
 "answerCount": 1,
 "answerScore": 0,
 "score": 0,
 "id": 1,
 "postType": "question",
 "viewCount": 1,
 "ownerUserId": -1,
 "tags": "|stackoverflow-for-teams|",
 "title": "What are the points associated with my profile?",
 "bodyMarkdown": "What is a reputation point and how do I earn them?",
 "body": "<p>What is a reputation point and how do I earn them?</p>\n"
}, {
 "creationDate": "2021-04-04T11:47:48.813Z",
 "favoriteCount": 0,
 "commentCount": 0,
 "answerCount": 0,
 "answerScore": 0,
 "score": 0,
 "id": 2,
 "postType": "answer",
 "parentId": 1,
 "ownerUserId": -1,
 "bodyMarkdown": "Your reputation points are displayed in your profile and are an indication of how valuable your knowledge is to your team. You can earn points when your teammates think your question or answer was helpful. You also get points when the question asker feels that you’ve done a good job and accepts your answer.",
 "body": "<p>Your reputation points are displayed in your profile and are an indication of how valuable your knowledge is to your team. You can earn points when your teammates think your question or answer was helpful. You also get points when the question asker feels that you’ve done a good job and accepts your answer.</p>\n"
}]
```

#### Posts2Votes

```json
[{
 "creationDate": "2021-04-27T06:35:47.067Z",
 "voteTypeId": 26,
 "userId": 1,
 "postId": 2,
 "id": 1,
 "targetUserId": 1
}, {
 "creationDate": "2021-04-27T06:39:41.880Z",
 "voteTypeId": 2,
 "userId": 1,
 "postId": 1,
 "id": 2,
 "targetRepChange": 10,
 "targetUserId": -1
}]
```

#### Tags

```json
[{
 "isSpecialTag": false,
 "count": 5,
 "id": 1,
 "creationDate": "2021-04-04T11:47:48.813Z",
 "name": "stackoverflow-for-teams"
}, {
 "isSpecialTag": false,
 "count": 1,
 "id": 2,
 "creationDate": "2021-04-27T06:35:04.453Z",
 "name": "some tag name"
}]
```

#### Users

```json
[{
 "lastAccessDate": "2022-05-01T06:53:45.033Z",
 "creationDate": "2021-10-30T23:59:59.813Z",
 "answerCount": 1,
 "questionCount": 1,
 "goldBadges": 0,
 "silverBadges": 0,
 "bronzeBadges": 1,
 "views": 0,
 "reputation": 1,
 "id": 1,
 "userTypeId": "Admin",
 "accountId": 1,
 "lastModifiedDate": "2022-05-02T11:20:00Z",
 "lastLoginDate": "2022-05-02T16:33:56.3Z",
 "location": "Somewhere",
 "title": "Some title",
 "profileImageUrl": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ ....",
 "realName": "your realname",
 "displayName": "your displayname"
}]
```

#### Users2Badges

```json
[{
 "date": "2021-04-04T12:00:00.070Z",
 "badgeId": 6,
 "userId": 1,
 "id": 1
}]
```

Comment: The '[Download your Data](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387787-download-your-data)' FAQ Page should contain a Link to this current Thread/Answer as it contains much more (useful) Info... // Great also would be if a Download Link could be provided to a 'Demo.zip' File containing some "typical" Demo Data... :idea: // (I came from [this Qt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417892/3799241) but I would need some Demo/Sample Data to build/test some (easy) Implementation/Script/Solution...)

Comment: @chivracq I've added example data.

Comment: Oh...!, excellent...!, @rene. // OK, then in `users.json`, for more than 1 User, the Format will be `[{Data_User_1}, {Data_User_2}, [...], {Data_User_n}]`...

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a private version of Data Explorer offered. That said, you can download all the Teams data for backup by following the instructions here:

https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387787-download-your-data

This would provide the information as a zip of JSON files. One thing to note is you would need a separate tool for filtering through the data.

Comment: Great, backup is already something ... I will test next week,  returning here my opinion on the structure and readability of the backup file.