# Due to inactivity, my Stack Overflow for Teams will get deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have received this email after creating and using my free Stack Overflow for Teams account.

> Hi there,
>
> Due to inactivity, your Stack Overflow for Teams account will be deleted in 15 days.
>
> If you’d like to be able to use your Team, please take action such as creating new content, adding a team member, or searching for content. Any of these actions will bring your account back to active status.
>
> If you do not take action, we will delete your account in 15 days.

**Q: What was the decision making behind creating this statement?**

I'd much rather be given the opportunity to "download" or "archive" my team's data, instead of it accidentally being deleted altogether.

(Using a comparison, that feels like deleting all Stack Overflow content that hasn't been viewed in *N* amount of days.)

---

> It's not a great campaign to threaten people if they don't use their content. It makes me not want to use it, much less upgrade to a paid option.

Oleg Valter puts it nicely in the comments below: (emphasis added)

> The fact that such a trivial action like searching for something resets the countdown **only confirms that this action is unnecessary** as it seems to be aimed to catch completely dead accounts, but manages to annoy users with active accounts that are not beaming with activity. And if this is a way to reduce the number of free accounts, then, frankly, SE shouldn't have made a "free tier" in the first place then, but they did, and launched a giant marketing campaign as well.

Comment: "_I'm going to feel very bad if my team's resources are deleted without me noticing._" But you _should_ notice because you just got informed that it might happen right? "_feels like deleting all Stack Overflow content that hasn't been viewed in N amount of days_" SO content is public while your team is not and I think that makes the scenarios very different.

Comment: "or searching for content".. that seems easy enough, no?

Comment: @takendarkk It is poor user experience to harshly punish someone for not reading every single email Stack Overflow sends.

Comment: @Scratte Yes it is easy. But it's unneeded stress for me. It's not a great campaign to threaten people if they don't use their content. It makes me not want to use it, much less upgrade to a paid option.

Comment: I don't think it is a harsh punishment to delete content which you are not using or even looking at which is not available to anyone else. "_It makes me not want to use it_" But you aren't even using it now so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @takendarkk That's exactly what I want. I also want my private savings account to disappear, sure. Jokes aside, this makes me want to use another product to store my information (And if that was the thought process behind this feature, then that's ok. If not, then they need to know people are feeling this way.)

Comment: "_use another product to store my information_"  So you are using Teams as a free DB? If that is the case then I would expect you to encounter issues since that is not what the product was designed for - it is a collaboration tool. If you just want to "store" stuff why not use a repository or a filesharing site like dropbox or something?

Comment: @takendarkk I like how it's in an encyclopedia format, it's a really great user experience. Since the product was not designed for that, I will use something else instead, no problem.

Comment: jeez the reception went bad. Frankly speaking this wording is harsh, and the idea is quite ridiculous. I understand when Google sends me an email that an unused Google Cloud Project will be deleted in N days because those offer *massive* amounts of features and likely take an equally massive amount of quotas. When SE sends the same email for a team 1-5 people for a about a month of inactivity, that's a whole other matter. Not everyone uses Teams frequently. People also take long breaks or not be active in general. The fact that such a trivial action like *searching* for something resets the...

Comment: ...countdown only confirms that this action is unnecessary as it seems to be aimed to catch completely dead accounts, but manages to annoy users with active accounts that are not beaming with activity. And if this is a way to reduce the number of free accounts, then, frankly, SE shouldn't have made a "free tier" in the first place then, but they did, and launched a giant marketing campaign as well.

Comment: [*I'd much rather be given the opportunity to "download" or "archive" my team's data, instead of it accidentally being deleted altogether.*](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387787-download-your-data) see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406973/private-data-explorer-for-a-private-stack-overflow-instance/407200#407200

Comment: @0-1 But your not using it, if your getting an email, about inactivity on your Team account.  You are not paying to store data.  Your expectation of a free tier of a paid service is pretty strange.

Comment: *"Using a comparison, that feels like deleting all Stack Overflow content that hasn't been viewed in N amount of days."* that actually happens regularly, though it could be a bit more strict

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This campaign is an effort to re-engage free teams that seem to have been created, previewed, and then did not go anywhere. It is targeted only at free teams that have no activity over the past two weeks **and only have one member** - simply adding a second user would immediately make you ineligible for inactivity deletion, because we are only trying to catch the cases where it feels like they just never bothered to "complete setup" of their team. We do nothing with multi-user teams.

If, after the warning, they cannot be re-engaged, we assume they were not interested in the product and delete the team so we are not using up data center resources. This especially helps us to not waste resources on teams created by bots that had no intention of using the product at all.

If you are worried about losing your data, you can always [download your data](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387787-download-your-data) at any time.

Comment: _"We do not send warnings to multi-user teams. If they cannot be re-engaged, we assume they were not interested in the product and delete the team"_ This is a bit ambiguous and could be interpreted as "multi-user teams are deleted without warning", which I assume is not what you meant because it contradicts with the text that precedes that part. Or maybe I misunderstood something?