# How can I get user reputation data for my private Team in tabular/spreadsheet form?

Tags: support, reputation, stack-overflow-for-teams, data

As an administrator of a Private Team on Stack Overflow for Teams, is there a way to obtain the reputation data of all users (Team members) in a spreadsheet?

I have seen [Private Data-explorer for a private Stack Overflow instance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406973/private-data-explorer-for-a-private-stack-overflow-instance), but this is about backing up data from the entire Team site in a format called JSON which appears quite far away from an easily readable spreadsheet (e.g., in Excel) - as least to someone who is not a computer technician or engineer.

Is there some way to download the reputation data in a spreadsheet (or convert the JSON data into a spreadsheet form in a way accessible to someone not trained in computer science or programming)?

Comment: @RobertLongson This helps! It didn't dawn on me that JSON was a general format. Thank you!

Comment: FYI you can also import JSON into Excel using the Data Import Wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft suggest](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) that you can just import json files directly into Excel these days.

> Select Data > Get Data > From File > From JSON. The Import Data dialog box appears.
>
> Locate the JSON file, and then select Open.

If that doesn't do what you want then there are plenty of online converters that claim to be able to convert json into either Excel or csv format.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Longson mentioned, you could import the `json` file into Microsoft Excel, using the Data Import Wizard.

Otherwise, you can also automate the process using a `python` script and integrating `dataframe`. Something like this should do the job for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json (r'Path where the JSON file is saved\File Name.json')
df.to_csv (r'Path where the new CSV file will be stored\New File Name.csv', index = None)
```

This script will create a .CSV file for you which is easily opened using Microsoft Excel.